# How to correctly use direct component in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a simple route:

```
direct:in -> step1 -> step2 -> stepN -> direct:out
```

I want to use this like a function call:

```
consumer = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate()
producer = camelContext.createProducerTemplate()
producer.sendBody("direct:int", body)
consumer.receiveBody("direct:out", TYPE)
```

The problem is that when i call `producer.sendBody(...)` the thread is blocked. Also, due to the thread is blocked, i am not able to use consumer, so in result i got an exception that there is no consumer on `direct:out`.

I can use another thread for consumer, but my goal is to use camel route as function with input and output.

Also, i can use `producer.asyncSendBody(...)` but is this a correct way? This approach allows me to consume messages using `consumer`, but i think that there should be another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what steps 1, 2, N are doing it's not possible to definitively say what is happening, but assuming they do not block, then what you are seeing is because the `direct:out` can't be completed until something consumes that exchange. Since that call comes after `sendBody()` it can't complete - just as you see.

You have three options (maybe more):

1. Use `asyncSendBody()` as you noted.
2. Change from `direct:out` to `seda:out` which queues the Exchange, allowing the send to complete and the receive to proceed.
3. Remove the `"direct:out"` endpoint and change from `sendBody(Endpoint, Object)` to `sendBody(Endpoint, ExchangePattern, Object)` which returns the end-result body to the caller.

Option 3 seems like what you want to do anyway, and is simpler.

Comment: Ad 3) You can use requestXXX as that is for InOut, where as sendXXX is for InOnly

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot freely change the route, so the 3rd option is not applicable.
Also, one step in  route is blocking (as i found).

Currently, the best option as you recommended, is to use `seda`.
In case of `asyncSendBody` some inflight exchanges fail because of timeout (but this is because blocking step)